# wired connector selection

Tags: connector

I want to adapt a standard connector for all my projects. My projects include microelectronics done with a soldering iron, so 0.1” pitch is small enough for me and very convenient for soldering. I’m also not dealing with resistance/capacitance critical electronics (such as radio).

I’m searching for a connector that is:

- Widely used and common
- Non-proprietary
- Polarized (that’s why i don’t like simple pin headers
- Relatively small factor connector (best would be about half of pun headers)
- Well defined and non ambiguous design (such as jet and molex)
- Easy to solder and optionally pogo-plug support
- Both PCB and breadboard friendly versions (SMD and DIP terminals)
- 4 to 8 wires support

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic, unfortunately

Comment: hmm, i knew this would arise, but it’s not a shopping question. i don’t know how to rephrase it, but i want pointers on what connector should i research on

Comment: But opinion-based questions are also off topic.

Comment: "*Polarized (that’s why i don’t like simple pin headers*", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I want them to be non-reversible. Pin headers can be connected in reverse as well

Comment: @MrGerber I don’t ask for opinion but for a specific connector (or connectors if there are more than one that cover my requirements)

Comment: @Harry Svensson I think he means keyed

Comment: OK, Im sure I've seen questions like this being closed before, but if it's considered OK, let's see if anyone else wants to do your googling for you. It should be quite possible to put these search terms into the search filter of most component distributors websites. It's also possible to get in touch with them via email. That would be my suggestion

Comment: I did my homework and i was unable to find something satisfactory. That’s why i posted the question

Comment: @dzervas I like this question, you got so far 0 close votes = good. *I believe* that the reason for why the comments are pretty hectic is because the goal with this question is to find a connector right off the bat. A *better* question would be to explain **why** you feel that you need such a connector. So far there is no legitimate reason for you to need this. If the reason is because you are designing something for disabled people with memory problems, blind people, or simply disfigured hands or everything in between, then it makes much more sense. But as it is now, you will gather more fuzz

Comment: Maybe the polarised IDC connectors used for old hard discs, JTAG connectors etc? https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/pcb-connectors/idc-connectors/